# HG: Alternative to merging of repositories

Tags: mercurial

**What we have for now**:

  (
  **1**
  ) we have a single product with few components developed in separate Mercurial repositories (components are Desktop Client, Mobile Client, Server, etc).

  (
  **2**
  ) we use a revision number in version, like 1.0.0.REV

**What we want to have**:

  (
  **3**
  ) have a shared libraries between components (without commiting from one repository to another)

  (
  **4**
  ) have a common REV number in version for all components

**Question**: is it possible to have (**4**), (**5**) without merging all repositories into one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it can be solved using sub-repositories.

I suggest to setup all your different repositories as sub-repositories of a main repo, which could include your shared libraries (as a sub-repository or directly in the main repo) and the revision file containing your current revision number. Your current repos can remain intact with this method.

```
Main repo
|-.hg
|
|-Shared libraries
|
|-Desktop Client
|--.hg
|
|-Server
|--.hg
|
...
|
|-.hgsubstate
|-revision.xml
|
```

At every change in the default branch of any sub-repo, you will have to also commit a change in the main repo to point to the new head of its sub-repo.

Comment: Can you explain in more details about revision file. How it will be populated? As far as I understand each sub-repositories will have its own revision number, will not it?

Comment: The revision file will need to be accessed through relative path in each product, unless you duplicate it yourself in your different folders. If it is common to all, it is better to have a single revision file, and to keep it in the main repo. The bump to a new revision is either done manually for each build, or have your build server do it automatically (preferred!).

Comment: "Revision number" I meant Mercurial revision number. Is there a chance to have common HG revision number for all sub-repositories?

Comment: There are 2 revision numbers that you can refer to: revision number as a commit's zero-based index, or the 40 hex digits hash number. You should not use the first one, as it is local, and will not even make sense in a distributed environment. The latter can be used, and could be part of the release product for traceability, but do you really want it as part of your versionning scheme?

Comment: We use revision number as a zero-based index. I know it is local. But our history is linear in most cases and for linear history this revision version works. We also use repository tags which helps to locate exact revision if revision number do not match.

Comment: Then you can use the revision index of the main repo, if that is your intent. It will only be increased when a commit is made on the main repo, which should happen every time you change the head of a sub-repo, or for all changes in the common library. To access it, however, from your sub-repo, is another story. Either you store the current ID in a revision file, or you use a command line option such as: `hg log -r default --repository <Main repo>`